# how do i use substring in the following condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string with 80 characters length I am trying to substring this characters at certain index I did the following

```
Extract_32charcters_From_Begining = Text[0:32]
Extract_16charcters_after32index = Text[32:16]
```

in the above example I expected to get the first 32 characters at the beginning of the text  then extract 16 characters after index 32 in the text. `Extract_16charcters_after32index` always returns 0 length. any idea what i am doing wrong ?

usually in PHP I do

```
substr($text, 32, 16);
```

isn't the results should be same in python?

Comment: Read the docs for slicing.  You’ll find the second parameter is used differently.

Comment: Second number of a slice is index of first item (character) after the end of the slice. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need a negative step value which is `-1`

```
Extract_16charcters_after32index = Text[32:16:-1]
```

Comment: Have you read the question?